# Could not resolve field from <apex:inputField> value binding in page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom text area field `Description__c` on a custom object `Custom_Object__c`. I have a controller with a property (`global Custom_Object__c customObject {get;set;}`) which is being used here:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!shouldRender}">
    <apex:inputField value="{!customObject.Description__c}"
        label="{!$ObjectType.Custom_Object__c.fields.Description__c.label}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

When the page first loads, the correct existing value is put into the text box that is formed by the `inputField`, yet when I click a button that has an action of trying to update the customObject object, I get the error

> Could not resolve field 'Description__c' from  value binding '{!customObject.Description__c}' in page

I've seen cases where this error comes from trying to use `inputField` on a non-SObject object but this is both an SObject and a field on that SObject so this doesn't make any sense to me.

Also, this isn't a permissions error because I have both read and write access.

Comment: Can you post your controller/extension code? Is that possible that there are method called getCustomSObject() in your controller?

Comment: can't post it all but there isn't a method like that. The only way that object is being accessed is through the getter above

Comment: are there get/set property defined on customObject variable? (like public Custom_Object__c customObject{get; set;} )